# Access nested children in xml file parsed with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, tree, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am new to xml parsing. [This xml file](http://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS408en-GB.xml) has the following tree:

```
FHRSEstablishment
 |--> Header
 |    |--> ...
 |--> EstablishmentCollection
 |    |--> EstablishmentDetail
 |    |    |-->...
 |    |--> Scores
 |    |    |-->...
 |--> EstablishmentCollection
 |    |--> EstablishmentDetail
 |    |    |-->...
 |    |--> Scores
 |    |    |-->...
```

but when I access it with ElementTree and look for the `child` tags and attributes,

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib2
tree = ET.parse(
   file=urllib2.urlopen('http://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS408en-GB.xml' % i))
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
   print child.tag, child.attrib
```

I only get:

```
Header {}
EstablishmentCollection {}
```

which I assume means that their attributes are empty. Why is it so, and how can I access the children nested inside `EstablishmentDetail` and `Scores`?

**EDIT**

Thanks to the answers below I can get inside the tree, but if I want to retrieve values such as those in `Scores`, this fails:

```
for node in root.find('.//EstablishmentDetail/Scores'):
    rating = node.attrib.get('Hygiene')
    print rating
```

and produces

```
None
None
None
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yo have to iter() over your root.

that is `root.iter()` would do the trick!

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib2
tree =ET.parse(urllib2.urlopen('http://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS408en-GB.xml'))
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root.iter():
   print child.tag, child.attrib
```

**Output:**

```
FHRSEstablishment {}
Header {}
ExtractDate {}
ItemCount {}
ReturnCode {}
EstablishmentCollection {}
EstablishmentDetail {}
FHRSID {}
LocalAuthorityBusinessID {}
...
```

- To get all tags inside `EstablishmentDetail` you need to find that tag and then loop through its children!

That is, for example.

```
for child in root.find('.//EstablishmentDetail'):
    print child.tag, child.attrib
```

**Output:**

```
FHRSID {}
LocalAuthorityBusinessID {}
BusinessName {}
BusinessType {}
BusinessTypeID {}
RatingValue {}
RatingKey {}
RatingDate {}
LocalAuthorityCode {}
LocalAuthorityName {}
LocalAuthorityWebSite {}
LocalAuthorityEmailAddress {}
Scores {}
SchemeType {}
NewRatingPending {}
Geocode {}
```

- To get the score for `Hygiene` as you've mentioned in comment,

What you have done is, it will get the first `Scores` tag and that will have Hygiene, ConfidenceInManagement, Structural tags as child when you call `for each in root.find('.//Scores'):rating=child.get('Hygiene')`. That is, obviously all three child will not have the element!

You need to first 
 - find all `Scores` tag.
 - find `Hygiene` in every tags found!

```
for each in root.findall('.//Scores'):
    rating = each.find('.//Hygiene')
    print '' if rating is None else rating.text
```

Output:

```
5
5
5
0
5
```

Comment: Wow, this was good, but I still struggle to get the ultimate values, such as the scores. If I do `for child in root.find('.//Scores'):
    rating = child.get('Hygiene');
    print rating;` I get `None` as a result.

Comment: What does .// do? Is this a regular expression?

Comment: So many posts about how to do this and none of them worked. This is the first one that told me to use `root.iter()` the only thing that worked. Nice job!

Answer (score 3):

Hope it could be useful:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
with open('filename.xml') as tmpfile:
    doc = etree.iterparse(tmpfile, events=("start", "end"))
    doc = iter(doc)
    event, root = doc.next()
    num = 0
    for event, elem in doc:
        print event, elem
```

Comment: `event, root = doc.next()`  `AttributeError: 'IterParseIterator' object has no attribute 'next'`

Comment: My script works on python2, for python3 use:
event, root = doc.__next__()